# How can I toggle between three canvases (HTML)?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

https://www.codepile.net/pile/Lobdr3DV

This is a link to my code, I am essentially trying to make three canvases over top of eachother. There will be 1 button for each canvas and clicking the button will hide the other two canvases and make the active one visible.

```
function swapCanvases1() {
  canvas.style.visibility='hidden';
  canvas2.style.visibility='hidden';
  canvas3.style.visibility='visible';
}

function swapCanvases2() {
  canvas.style.visibility='hidden';
  canvas2.style.visibility='visible';
  canvas3.style.visibility='hidden';
}

function swapCanvases3() {
  canvas.style.visibility='visible';
  canvas2.style.visibility='hidden';
  canvas3.style.visibility='hidden';
}
```

I tried doing this but if you try to run my code in browser, all the canvases appear on the screen side by side, and never get hidden even when I press the respective button.

Some help would be awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code could use some serious refactoring, anyways this: `img.src=...` seems to be the issue. There is no img variable set, so the onclick functions end up on an error (so these swap functions don't even run), which you should see in the developer console (F12).

Also consider doing `display='none/block';` instead of `visibility='visible/hidden';` or set the canvases `position: absolute;` to overlap.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for this comment. I tried implementing some of the changes you suggested. For now I just got rid of the images and am instead just changing the color of the ball. The canvases are now overlapping, but it doesn't seem to work when I try to change from one to another.